# How to add variable to each item in a set in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to add string --foo to each element in given set and been trying hard to do that but unable to do. Is it really possible to do that?
Below is the set

```
a = {"apple", "banana", "cherry", "6363738", "1"}
```

output

```
a = {"apple--foo", "banana--foo", "cherry--foo", "6363738-foo", "1-foo"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string concatenation in a set comprehension

```
>>> {i+'--foo' for i in a}
{'banana--foo', '6363738--foo', 'apple--foo', 'cherry--foo', '1--foo'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
a = {"apple", "banana", "cherry", "6363738", "1"}
{"{}--foo".format(i) for i in a}
```

or for Python 3.6 and above

```
{f"{i}--foo" for i in a}
```

Output

```
{"apple--foo", "banana--foo", "cherry--foo", "6363738-foo", "1-foo"}
```

Comment: That right for Python 3.6 and higher but for lower versions format will be better.

Comment: One would hope that pre-3.6 deployments are diminishing rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to accomplish this, here is a simple for loop:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] += "--foo"
```

Comment: This just adds an additional set element `"--foo"` for each existing element; it does not append `--foo` to each element of the set. (Nor would `item += "--foo"`, because `str` values are immutable.)

Comment: That was a typo, but you are correct. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

For a change, using `lambda`:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x + '--foo', a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> set(map(lambda x: x + '--foo', a)) # {'apple--foo', '6363738--foo', '1--foo', 'cherry--foo', 'banana--foo'}
```